# ¿Cómo puedo retornar un valor de un setOnMouseClicked para usarlo como parámetro en método List?

Tags: java, javafx

Necesito usar que la variable User que se encuentra fuera de Start pueda cambiar del valor, ya que hay un evento de mouse que permite obtener el nombre de chats, es para que me muestre el chat de los que he creado y filtrado por nombre, por lo que necesito saber cómo retornar un valor dentro de un evento, y usarlo de parámetro. Lo he intentado, pero no se me viene idea a la mente.

```
public class App extends Application {
     
        public String User;
        String userFrom = "Yo";
        int id ;
    
    
    
        MessageRepository messageRepository = new MessageRepository();
        ContactRepository contactRepository = new ContactRepository();
    
           
    
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    
           
    
             // Verde
             ScrollPane scrollPane2 = new ScrollPane();
             scrollPane2.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
             scrollPane2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #77ff33");
             scrollPane2.setPrefWidth(300);
            
             
             VBox vBox2 = new VBox();
     
             scrollPane2.setContent(vBox2);
            
     
             List <Contact> res= contactRepository.getContacts(id);
             
             
     
             for (Contact usr: res) {
                 Image image1 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("./Images/Armando.png"));
                 ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image1);
                 imageView.setFitHeight(50);
                 imageView.setFitWidth(50);
                 FlowPane flowPane2 = new FlowPane(10,10);
                 flowPane2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #77ff33");
                 Label lblUser = new Label(usr.getDate());
                 Label lblName = new Label(usr.getNombreContact());
                 
    
                 flowPane2.setOnMouseClicked( event -> {
                    String result = String.valueOf(lblName.getText());
                         User=result;
                         System.out.print(User);
                    
                 });
     
     
                 flowPane2.getChildren().addAll(imageView,lblName,lblUser);
                 vBox2.getChildren().add(flowPane2);
                 
                 
             }
    
             
    
            List<Mensaje> resultMe= messageRepository.getMessage(User, userFrom);
            
            // ROJO
            ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
            scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
            scrollPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#FF3333");
            
    
            VBox vBox = new VBox();
    
            scrollPane.setContent(vBox);
    
            // String User = "Armando";
            System.out.print(User); 
           
    
           
    
            for (Mensaje msg: resultMe) {
                FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane(10,10);
                Label lblImage = new Label(msg.getFrom());
                Label lblMessage = new Label(msg.getContent());
                flowPane.getChildren().addAll(lblImage);
                flowPane.getChildren().addAll(lblMessage);
                vBox.getChildren().add(flowPane);
                
            }
    
          
    
            FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
            flowPane.setPrefHeight(50);
            flowPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ddd");
    
            TextField input = new TextField();
            input.setPromptText("Escribe un mensaje aqui");
    
    
            Button btn = new Button("Send");
            btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    
                    Image image1 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("./Images/Luis.png"));
                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image1);
                    imageView.setFitHeight(50);
                    imageView.setFitWidth(50);
                    FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
                    Label lblMessage = new Label(input.getText());
    
                    flowPane.getChildren().add(lblMessage);
                    flowPane.getChildren().add(imageView);
                    vBox.getChildren().add(flowPane);
                }
            });
    
            flowPane.getChildren().addAll(input,btn);
    
    
    
    
            AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
            root.getChildren().addAll(scrollPane,scrollPane2,flowPane);
    
    
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(scrollPane, 50.0);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(scrollPane, 300.0);
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(scrollPane, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(scrollPane, 0.0);
            
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(flowPane, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(flowPane, 300.0);
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(flowPane, 0.0);
    
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(scrollPane2, 50.0);
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(scrollPane2, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(scrollPane2, 0.0);
    
            
    
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,1290,720);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Discordia");
            primaryStage.show();
    
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
}
```

Comment: Se te solicitaba más explicación porque efectivamente tu pregunta es más código que la descripción de la misma. ¡Ya no agregues ruido! Debes adjuntar un [repro] (énfasis en _mínimo_) de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask].

Comment: ya intentaste cambiar su ambito a clase?

Comment: lo que pasa es que `List<Mensaje> resultMe= messageRepository.getMessage(User, userFrom);`   sucede solo una vez y aunque  `flowPane2.setOnMouseClicked`    cambie `User`  en `flowPane2.setOnMouseClicked`  este no va a actualizar  `List<Mensaje> resultMe= messageRepository.getMessage(User, userFrom);`

Comment: pregunta `System.out.print(User);`  en  `flowPane2.setOnMouseClicked`   imprime algo cuando haces click en flowpane ?  la variable User cambia ?

Comment: Efectivamente se cambia el valor pero dentro del for, lo que quisiera es que el valor salga del for para que lo pueda usar y asi cambie, con respecto al print si efectivamente me da los nombres dentro del for, pero fuera de este me imprime nulo.

Comment: lo único malo es que no puedo reproducir su proyecto . hay demasiadas clases que no están . Pero podría cambiar `String User` a `StringProperty User = new SimpleStringProperty()`   ese objeto puede escuchar cambios